# Perl: Convert array of keys and values into a hash

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I have two arrays like this

```
my @keys = qw/Key_1 Key_2 Key_3/;
my @values = qw/foo bar more/;
```

Is there a short way (i.e. a single function) to get a hash like this without using a loop?

```
my %hash_table = ( Key_1 => "foo", Key_2 => "bar", Key_3 => "more" );
```

I tried to use `map` function but no success.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use a hash [slice](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices),

```
my %hash_table;
@hash_table{@keys} = @values;
```

using map,

```
my %hash_table = map { $keys[$_] => $values[$_] } 0 .. $#keys;
```